# What's the syntax error in this simple mysql query?

Tags: mysql

What's the syntax error in this simple mysql query?

```
create table table1(
    date DATE PRIMARY KEY,
    open float(10,6),
    high float(10,6),
    low float(10,6),
    close float(10,6),
    volume INT(10),
    adj_close float(10,6);
```

Comment: Formatting makes it a bit easier to spot some mistakes (such as a missing `)`).

Comment: I'm calling your attention here to that `PRIMARY KEY`. Make sure that it's what you want since it will allow you to only have one row of given date.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing parenthesis.  Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
    date DATE PRIMARY KEY,
    open FLOAT(10,6),
    high float(10,6),
    low FLOAT(10,6),
    close FLOAT(10,6),
    volume INT(10),
    adj_close FLOAT(10,6)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your CREATE TABLE statement with a `)`

```
create table table1(date DATE PRIMARY KEY, open float(10,6), high float(10,6), low float(10,6), close float(10,6), volume INT(10), adj_close float(10,6));
```